# Help me find this old bloody anime fantasy movie

Tags: legend-of-lemnear

I have been looking for an anime movie I saw a long time ago for many years now and would be grateful for any help. It was a fairly bloody and graphic movie in a dark style and included female nudity (exposed breasts) and at least one scene with an attempted rape.

1. The movie was probably from the 80s or 90s
2. The protagonist was a woman with some sort of magical power symbolized by the metal bronze. The main villain had the 'gold' power and there was a male character with the 'silver' power who helped the main character in the final battle.
3. There was one scene where another woman is about to be raped by a guard/warrior and the main character runs in without her top on, kills the guard with some sort of blade and then takes something from the room for clothing.
4. In her initial battle with the gold villain the main character is killed or at least badly injured but then is revived by some power and goes to fight him again.
5. The gold villain could change his form and in the final battle turned into some sort of giant dragon like monster before the silver and bronze characters killed him working together.

I saw this movie on DVD and I believe it was dubbed. It was probably rented from blockbuster so it had some sort of American release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Could you be thinking of Legend of Lemnear?

This is a 45 minute OVA that has a female protagonist who is a a champion of silver, there are two other champions as well, one of gold and one of bronze.

---

From [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/434/Legend_of_Lemnear:_Kyokuguro_no_Tsubasa_Valkisas):

> The young and beautiful Lemnear's home village is destroyed and her brother is taken away. Lemnear swears to kill the evil wizard Gardin who is responsible for the disaster. With her allies Lemnear goes on a journey to take her revenge. She doesn't know, though, that there is someone above Gardin...

---

Cover:

[image]

Comment: This is the one! I must have seen this when I was only six or seven. It hasn't aged that well but this was the first anime movie I ever saw and it's what got me into anime. This was my roots but I never could find it again until now! I'm really glad you found this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, had you seen it before and recognized it by the description, or did you do a blind search?

Comment: It's on my plan-to-watch list but I haven't seen it yet. I heard that it's not that good of a parody so it's kind of low priority.

Answer (score 2):

[Is it Saint Seiya?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Seiya)  The time period matches, the article mentions dragon transformation, and of course bronze, silver, and gold linked powers.

> Ages ago, the goddess Athena was served by fighters called Saints who channeled the power of the Cosmos within them. Now a youth named Seiya has trained to become a Saint himself by earning the mystical Cloth of Pegasus. He is joined by other Saints with Cloths of their own to fight for Athena.
>
> [image]

Comment: I don't think so. It does have the metal linked powers but I looked at the movies and the style is very different. None of the movies have scenes I remember and it has a team of heroes working together instead of the one female protagonist. There isn't much blood or killing and definitely no nudity. If it helps I'm thinking I could be wrong about the time period. It could have been later (90s and maaybe early 2000s?). Thank you for the help though! This has been stumping me for years.

Comment: [Heroic Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroic_Age_%28anime%29) is 2007, so I'm guessing that's not it... which means there are at least 3 anime with gold/silver/bronze themes. Huh... I'll keep checking.